# Run the right scripts before deployment elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am editing my `.ebextensions` `.config` file to run some initialisation commands before deployment. I thought this commands would be run in the same folder of the extracted .zip containing my app. But that's not the case. `manage.py` is in the root directory of my zip and if I do the commands:

```
  01_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

I get a `ERROR: [Instance: i-085e84b9d1df851c9] Command failed on instance. Return code: 2 Output: python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.`

I could do `command: "python /opt/python/current/app/manage.py collectstatic --noinput"` but that would run the `manage.py` that successfully was deployed previously instead of running the one that is being deployed atm.

I tried to check what was the working directory of the commands ran by the `.config` by doing `command: "pwd"` and it seems that pwd is `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/eb_infra` which doesn't contain my app.

So I probably need to change `$PYTHONPATH` to contain the right path, but I don't know which path is it.

In this [comment](https://realpython.com/blog/python/deploying-a-django-app-and-postgresql-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk/#comment-2849390172) the user added the following to his .config file:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: myapp.settings
    PYTHONPATH: "./src"
```

Because his `manage.py` lives inside the src folder within the root of his zip. In my case I would do `PYTHONPATH: "."` but it's not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AWS support solved the problem. Here's their answer:

When Beanstalk is deploying an application, it keeps your application files in a "staging" directory while the EB Extensions and Hook Scripts are being processed. Once the pre-deploy scripts have finished, the application is then moved to the "production" directory. The issue you are having is related to the "manage.py" file not being in the expected location when your "01_collectstatic" command is being executed.

The staging location for your environment (Python 3.4, Amazon Linux 2017.03) is "/opt/python/ondeck/app".

The EB Extension "commands" section is executed *before* the staging directory is actually created. To run your script once the staging directory has been created, you should use "container_commands". This section is meant for modifying your application after the application has been extracted, but before it has been deployed to the production directory. It will automatically run your command in your staging directory.

Can you please try implementing the container_command section and see if it helps resolve your problem? The syntax will look similar to this (but please test it before deploying to production):

```
container_commands:
  01_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the thing to remember about beanstalk is that each of the commands are independent, and you do **not** maintain state between them.  You have two options in this case, put your commands into a shell script that is [uploaded in the `files` section of `ebextensions`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-files).  Or, you can write one line commands that do all stateful activities prefixed to your command of interest.

e.g.,

```
00_collectstatic:
    command: "pushd /path/to/django && source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && popd"
```

Comment: Thanks for that info. But the main problem is that I don't know which /path/to/django to use. /opt/python/current/app contains the previously successful deployed app, how do I run commands in the app that I'm trying to deploy now?